# bootstrap active class nth-child()

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have bootstrap tabs, I wish to change the state of the active tab, I can do this easily like so

```
.side-nav-cat .active {
    border: 25px solid #888888;
}
```

however I wish to have different styles depending on the `nth-child`, I have tried

```
.side-nav-cat .active li:nth-child(1) {
    border-left: 25px solid #888888;
}
.side-nav-cat .active li:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: 25px solid #628179;
}
```

But this dose not work, I am just using CSS is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just have to change your selector to : `.side-nav-cat li:nth-child(1).active`

Here it select the first `li` with the class `active` with your selector it search child of `.active` class.

```css
.side-nav-cat li:nth-child(1).active {
    border-left: 25px solid #888888;
}
.side-nav-cat li:nth-child(2).active {
    border-left: 25px solid #628179;
}
```

```html
<ul class="side-nav-cat">
  <li class="active">1</li>
  <li class="active">2</li>
  <li class="active">3</li>
</ul>
```